# float VS floatN

Tags: opencl

Is there any advantage when using floatN instead float in OpenCL?

for example

```
float3 position;
```

and

```
float posX, posY, posZ;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the hardware.

NVidia GPUs have a scalar architecture, so vectors provide little advantage on them over writing purely scalar code.  Quoting the [NVidia OpenCL best practices guide](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/CUDABrowser/downloads/papers/NVIDIA_OpenCL_BestPracticesGuide.pdf) (PDF link):

> The CUDA architecture is a scalar architecture. Therefore, there is no performance
>   benefit from using vector types and instructions. These should only be used for
>   convenience. It is also in general better to have more work-items than fewer using
>   large vectors.

With CPUs and ATI GPUs, you will gain more benefits from using vectors as these architectures have vector instructions (though I've heard this might be different on the latest Radeons - wish I had a link to the article where I read this).

Quoting the [ATI Stream OpenCL programming guide](http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/ATI_Stream_SDK_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) (PDF link), for CPUs:

> The SIMD floating point resources in a CPU (SSE) require the use of
>   vectorized types (float4) to enable packed SSE code generation and extract
>   good performance from the SIMD hardware.

[This article](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/Pages/OpenCL-Optimization-Case-Study_7.aspx) provides a performance comparison on ATI GPUs of a kernel written with vectors vs pure scalar types.

Comment: AMD's latest "Graphics Core Next" (aka GCN) architecture that powers the Radeon HD 7900 series uses a 16-wide SIMD as the fundamental compute unit, so there's still good reason to use vector types.

Comment: Thank you to all of you guys for all the answers :)

Comment: @user57368: Actually from what I understand GCN goes the same way NVidia does and exposes only a scalar architecture to the program, so there wouldn't be any good reason to use vector types there. Afterall NVidia also uses 16-wide SIMD units on fermi, but they are exposed as 16 scalar units. So this should greatly diminish the usefullness of vectortypes on gpus (and bring programming for nvidia and amd closer together which is a good thing)

Comment: The only scalar part of a GCN compute unit is the special functions unit that handles branches and transcendental functions. The basic ALUs are in blocks of 16 that all run the same instruction at the same time. If you don't use vector types, you are relying on the compiler being able to appropriately schedule instructions and unroll loops in order to get full utilization. Explicitly using vector types can't hurt, and can only make the compiler's job easier.

Comment: @user57368: Again from what I've read gcn goes the same way nvidia did and exposes a scalar architecture (where 16 threads (or more?) follow the same execution path). I never said the underlying architecture was scalar (again fermi is programmed as if it was scalar, but uses 16wide simd). The compiler doesn't do any scheduling/unrolling for that, since each thread is basically calculating one data element of the simd block. Therefore using vectortypes (exspecially 16 wide) isn't likely to make the compilers job any easier and can actually hurt performance by adding to the register pressure.

Answer (score 2):

In both Nvidia and AMD architectures, the memory is divided into banks of 128 bits. Often, reading a single float3 or float4 value is going to be faster for the memory controller than reading 3 separate floats.

When you read float values from consecutive memory addresses, you are relying heavily on the compiler to combine the reads for you. There is no guarantee that posX, posY, and posZ are in the same bank. Declaring it as float3 usually forces the locations of the component floats to fall within the same bank.

How the GPUs handle the vector computations varies between the vendors, but the memory accesses on both platforms will benefit from from the vectorization.

Comment: I think this might be true although nvidia meant differently when they stated that there is no benefit from using vector instructions. However, do you have backup when saying that using float3/float4 the locations of the components fall into the same bank? Doesn't this also depend on the compiler?

Comment: Definitely compiler dependant. Although I can't think of a reason why the compiler/driver would make vector types slower. Many pixel types are 3 or floats in size, and gpus need to optimize for that at lease.

Comment: I agree and if you have concrete evidence such as some experiments I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with OpenCL, but in GLSL doing math with vectors is more efficient because the GPU can apply the same operation to all N components concurrently. Also, in GLSL vectors also support operations like dot products as built-in language features.