# PyOpenCL reduction Kernel on each pixel of image as array instead of each byte (RGB mode, 24 bits )

Tags: numpy, pyopencl

I'm trying to calculate the average [Luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28relative%29) of an RGB image. To do this, I find the luminance of each pixel i.e.

`L(r,g,b) = X*r + Y*g + Z*b (some linear combination).`

And then find the average by summing up luminance of all pixels and dividing by width*height.
To speed this up, I'm using  [pyopencl.reduction.ReductionKernel](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/algorithm.html)

The array I pass to it is a Single Dimension Numpy Array so it works just like the example given.

```
import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('image_00000001.bmp')
data = np.asarray(im).reshape(-1) # so data is a single dimension list
# data.dtype is uint8, data.shape is (w*h*3, )
```

I want to incorporate the following code from the example into it . i.e. I would make changes to datatype and the type of arrays I'm passing. This is the example:

```
a = pyopencl.array.arange(queue, 400, dtype=numpy.float32)
b = pyopencl.array.arange(queue, 400, dtype=numpy.float32)

krnl = ReductionKernel(ctx, numpy.float32, neutral="0",
        reduce_expr="a+b", map_expr="x[i]*y[i]",
        arguments="__global float *x, __global float *y")

my_dot_prod = krnl(a, b).get()
```

Except, my map_expr will work on each pixel and convert each pixel to its luminance value.
And reduce expr remains the same.

The problem is, it works on each element in the array, and I need it to work on each pixel which is 3 consecutive elements at a time (RGB ).

One solution is to have three different arrays, one for R, one for G and one for B ,which would work, but is there another way ?

Comment: You could use a vector float. However, I think you will have to use a float4 and kind of not use one element, which is then overhead. I am not 100% sure, but as far as I know there can be situations when it is better to sue vector types then scalar ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933604/float-vs-floatn)). I can provide an example if you want. You can of course always also define your own vector with three components.

Comment: Could you provide an example please ? I mean, is it as simple as changing the arguments to __global float4 *x ? And that automatically chooses them 4 at a time ? would there be alignment issues if this one dimensional array had to be taken 3 at a time instead of 4 ? I faced some packing and unpacking issues in OpenGL, may not be related but just to be sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I changed the program to illustrate the char4 usage instead of float4:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array


deviceID = 0
platformID = 0
workGroup=(1,1)

N = 10
testData = np.zeros(N, dtype=cl_array.vec.char4)

dev = cl.get_platforms()[platformID].get_devices()[deviceID]

ctx = cl.Context([dev])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
Data_In = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE, testData.nbytes)


prg = cl.Program(ctx, """

__kernel void   Pack_Cmplx( __global char4* Data_In, int  N)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);

  //Data_In[gid] = 1; // This would change all components to one
  Data_In[gid].x = 1;  // changing single component
  Data_In[gid].y = 2;
  Data_In[gid].z = 3;
  Data_In[gid].w = 4;
}
 """).build()

prg.Pack_Cmplx(queue, (N,1), workGroup, Data_In, np.int32(N))
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, testData, Data_In)
print testData
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @andi, its slightly different though. test_data in my case is a `np.asarray(Image.open('xyz.bmp')).reshape(-1)`. So it is essentially a single dimensional array of uchar values. If I had to take 4 of these uchar values at a time, in the ReductionKernel part, I would have to change arguments to `__global uchar4* Data_in`. Is that correct ?

Comment: I have nothing to test at hand at the moment, but sounds right to me. You can check the OpenCL vector data types [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/vectorDataTypes.html) or in the OpenCL [specifications](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=200) on page 200.